Translating "He is my always" and "She is my forever"
My fiancé would like 2 Latin phrases for our wedding day to display, but we are struggling with the translation from English to Latin.
The phrases we would like to translate are 'He is my always' and 'She is my forever'.

Uff... Latin had no word meaning specifically "forever", so the second one is going to be quite a bit tricky.

@FlatAssembler True that in perpetuum is not a single word, but neither was forever when it originally appeared as for ever.

It looks like you're using "always" and "forever" as nouns, rather than adverbs as they normally are. English can easily do this but Latin can't really change an adverb into a noun like that, so the closest would probably be "He is mine always" and "She is mine forever".

If you really meant "my" and not "mine", you could also use a real noun like "mea aeternitas", which means "(he/she is) my eternity".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I suggest:

Meus semper, mea in perpetuum.
[He is] mine always, [she is] mine forever."

Meus/mea/meum est is a quite common way of saying "he/she/it is mine" (though, like English, it's not always romantic).
You could also play with the word order:

Semper meus, mea in perpetuum.
[He is] always mine, [she is] mine forever."

Doing it this latter way creates a nice chiasm (ABBA structure) that looks nicer, in my opinion, though there's nothing wrong with the parallel structure (ABAB).

There are many ways to say this. In addition to the excellent answers already mentioned, you could say, Perpetua mea haec, hic meus aeternus. This would preserve the trick of having two different substantives meaning the same thing, one in each gender.

Along these lines, you could also say is (hic) mea perpetuitas, ea (haec) mea aeternitas.

@cmw Indeed. Ille and ipse are also options, each with slightly different emphasis. I'm not certain which emphasis the OP has in mind. I settled on hic because it seemed to me to be the most intimate (This guy, right here!) but I could also make a case for the other options, as you just did for is.

Oh, I wasn't really making a particular case for is over hic, but using the abstract nouns as a possibility instead of an adjective.

"He is my always." can be translated as "Is est semper meus.", with "always" being translated as "semper". "She is my forever." is a little trickier, as Latin doesn't have a word meaning specifically "forever". Perhaps we can paraphrase this as "She is my for all times." and translate it as "Ea est mea pro omnibus temporibus.". Or, if you want to sound fancy, perhaps you could say "Mea est omnibus pro temporibus.", changing the word order so that the adjective goes before the preposition, as in the famous Latin phrase "summa cum laude".

That would be the translation for "mine" instead of "my". Either the OP made a mistake or meant what TKR suggested in a comment to the question.

"pro" isn't used for duration of time. But "per" can be. At least in later Latin "per omnia tempora" can be used to mean "throughout all time."
